# Strange behavior with read.table

Tags: r

I have a large input file with data that looks like this:

```
345 33
671 34
304 35
266 36
```

Seems pretty standard. But I can't find any read.table parameters that even recognizes that there are two columns. The table that gets created is a column of seemingly random single-digit numbers, or an error saying that every line appears to contain embedded nulls. If I type lines <- "{data}", lines becomes

```
345\t33\n671\t34\n304\t35\n266\t36
```

But when I tell the table sep="\t" it doesn't help. I do have a header but I'm using skip=1 to make sure it's not causing issues. Is there a formatting trick I'm not aware of? I'm going to be dealing with files in this format regularly so I'd love a relatively low-effort solution.

Comment: Have you tried fread from data.table?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Can you give the entire command line which uses `read.table` plz ?

Comment: `an error saying that every line appears to contain embedded nulls`: Have you tried `skipNul = TRUE`?

Comment: Update: fread did not work. Not sure how to give a reproducible example short of the lines output. Adding skipNul=T throws errors but works, and the resulting table seems accurate, so Scarabee has solved the problem. Thanks for your suggestions friends. The full read.table command is:

test_report <- read.table("<file>",skip=1,sep="\t",skipNul=T)

Comment: We really need more info to see what's going on. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for help. At the least, we need to know what your data looks like and what code you're running and in what order (for example, where is `lines<-""` being run, and why is the value of `lines` something else later?).

Comment: It's hard to know. Maybe there are particular lines causing trouble? If the file is as you show, with tabs and new lines, the default `read.table` works fine. Using the sample you share, `read.table(text = "345\t33\n671\t34\n304\t35\n266\t36")` works just fine.